# How Faye achieves cross-domain (XDR) pub/sub?

Tags: cross-domain, xss, security, publish-subscribe, faye

[Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) supports cross-domain subscription. Here is an excerpt from their docs:

> **Cross-domain operation**
>   Faye clients and servers transparently support
>   cross-domain communication, so your client can connect
>   to a server on any domain you like without further configuration.

Anyone knows how it achieves it?

Comment: I know I can dig through the documentation, but I thought someone might have already done it.

Answer (score 2):

Faye uses [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to send a handshake request to the server when it's cross-domain, as the author of Faye explains in his reply [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sockjs/WSIdcY14ciI/B9kot6nS73MJ). It then selects a new transport from a list, in order of preference: WebSocket, EventSource, XHR, CORS and JSON-P. Note that WebSockets, once established, can also work cross-domain as [previously discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042691/web-sockets-make-ajax-cors-obsolete).