# Understanding CORS and sending requests

Tags: ajax, node.js, rest, cors

I have multiple sites, and I want to consolidate similar functionality to a single server.

Economically it would make a lot more sense to set up one server that handles all the requests, than to set up a new server every time I get a new client. Especially when the functionality is almost identical.

For example, all of my sites have contact forms. I want site A, B, and C to all send ajax requests to a single Node.js server, which will process the request, and then send an email and log the information in a database.

I have read several questions pertaining to CORS and Node.js (using express) but I still haven't got it to work. So any help there would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if there are any sources that would help me understand better understand REST in general that would be nice.

EDIT: Here's the code --> https://gist.github.com/cyanogen32/8290499

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is way to general to be answered. You need to show what you tried that did not work. How did you set up the CORS? How did you make the request?

Comment: I edited the original post to include the code I'm working with.

Comment: Please add the code to the post - links go out of date and this question is there to help others in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web sockets make ajax/CORS obsolete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042691/web-sockets-make-ajax-cors-obsolete)

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with this:

```
app = express();
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    next();
});
```

Comment: I can confirm.  These are similar things I have had to put in some of my projects